# upload multiple images using dynamic reactive forms in angular

Tags: angular, api, angular11

What I'm trying to do is I'm uploading multiple images for a single product. I can't solution for this anywhere. I'm able to upload single image but when I try to send multiple images by adding dynamic form control it didn't work.

Below is my code I tried..

**Add.Component.html**

```
<div>
 <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">

 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="file" formControlName="image" (change)="uploadFile($event)">
 </div>

 <div class="form-group >
  <input type="text" formControlName="name">
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">

  <button type="button" (click)="addalternateImage()">Add Alternate Image</button>
  <div formArrayName="alternateImage" *ngFor="let image of alternateImage.controls; let i=index">
    <input [formControlName]="i" (change)="uploadFile($event)" type="file">
  </div>

 </div>

  <div class="form-group">
   <button >Upload</button>
  </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

**Add.componenet.ts**

```
export class AddComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string | any;
  image: any = [];

 constructor(private service: UploadService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {}

 // Adding alternate image control
 get alternateImage() {
  return this.form.get('alternateImage') as FormArray;
 }
 addalternateImage() {
   this.alternateImage.push(this.fb.control(''));
 }

  form = this.fb.group({
   name: [''],
   alternateImage: this.fb.array([]),
   })

  uploadFile(event: any) {
   this.alternateImage = event.target.files[0];
  }


  submitForm() {
   const formData: any = new FormData();
   formData.append("Name", this.form.controls['name'].value);
   formData.append("Image", this.alternateImage, this.alternateImage.name);

   }
  }
```

**I want data to be send like this**

```
{
  "name":"productname",
  "image":{ "img1" , "img2" , "img3" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is to keep a separate array of the images. The index of the image in the array is equivalent to its index in the form.

This is assuming you will only be working with one product at a time. If you were to have a form where you can dynamically add products and then images for every product, I would then use a 2D array (an array of images arrays).

TYPESCRIPT:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  productImageForm: FormGroup;
  images: any[];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.images = [];
    this.productImageForm = this.fb.group({
      productName: ['', Validators.required],
      images: this.fb.array([this.getImageFormGroup()]),
    });
  }

  private getImageFormGroup() {
    // keep place of added image control in images array
    this.images.push(undefined);
    return this.fb.group({
      imagePath: [null, Validators.required],
    });
  }

  get imagesFormArray() {
    return this.productImageForm?.get('images') as FormArray;
  }

  public addImageForm() {
    this.imagesFormArray.push(this.getImageFormGroup());
  }

  public removeImageForm(imageIndex: number): void {
    this.imagesFormArray.removeAt(imageIndex);
    // remove image from image array
    this.images.splice(imageIndex, 1);
  }

  public onFileChange(event: any, index: number): void {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    // replace image in images array
    this.images.splice(index, 1, file);
    if (!file) {
      this.imagesFormArray.controls[index].get('imagePath')?.patchValue(null);
    }
  }

  public submit(): void {
    // check that product name has been given
    // and that all image inputs have been utilized
    if (this.productImageForm.valid) {
      this.upload();
    } else {
      console.log('Form is not valid');
    }
  }

  private upload() {
    // check for max image size
    this.images.forEach((file) => {
      if (file.size > 10000000) {
        alert('Each File should be less than 10 MB of size.');
        return;
      }
    });

    const images = new FormData();

    this.images.forEach((image,) => {
      images.append('fileData', image);
    });

    this.uploadImages(images)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(
        (res) => {
          console.log('success');
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
  }
    
      private uploadImages(imagesToUpload: FormData): Observable<any> {
        const productName = this.productImageForm.get('productName').value;
        return this.http.post('yourEndpoint/' + productName, imagesToUpload);
      }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="productImageForm">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>ProductName</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" formControlName="productName" />
    </mat-form-field>
    <div formArrayName="images">
      <div
        class="card m-2 p-2"
        *ngFor="let image of imagesFormArray.controls; let i = index"
        [formGroupName]="i"
      >
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <input
            type="file"
            formControlName="imagePath"
            (change)="onFileChange($event, i)"
          />
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="removeImageForm(i)">
            <mat-icon>remove</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="addImageForm()">
        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button mat-rised-button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

In this example, I am using angular material.
If you want to use angular material, don't forget to add the necessary imports to your module:

MODULE.TS

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```